# Oracle setup database to share schema

Tags: schema, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking for the best way to setup an Oracle database so that multiple roles can share a single schema with tables.

I would have, for example, several roles:

- Application User
- N Developer Users
- DBA User
- ... future user types

I have been able to create groups, grant privileges to other schemas, and create a logon trigger to switch the schema on logon. However, users are not able to view tables through SQL Developer.

Comment: are the users switching manually to the correct schema in sql developer?  the alter session will not change the gui there.

Comment: I have verified that the current_schema property for the user set to the correct schema. Is it possible to make this seamless in the gui?

Comment: maybe you could go with public synonyms...  easier to just switch to the right on i think..

Comment: thanks. I'll give that a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer will only show the objects owned by the current user, not those that are owned by the session's `current_schema` setting, in the tree view unless you go to `Other Users` and choose the schema you're interested in.  In order to see objects owned by other users, you're realistically going to have to navigate to the appropriate schema.  If there are a large number of schemas in the database, you can right click on `Other Users` and create a filter that limits the set of users that are returned to just the schema you care about.